# What does $\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=\theta$ represent geometrically? ($a$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}$)

Tags: complex-numbers

Taking $z=x+iy$ and solving the equation algebraically shows that it is a circle but I cannot understand intuitively why this is so.

I would greatly appreciate a geometrical intuition behind this like there is with $|z-a|= r$ (postive numerical value), where $|z-a|$ represents the distance between $z$ and $a$, and $a$ being a fixed point, it represents a circle with radius $r$.

Also geometrical understanding of cases where $\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=\theta$ represent a pair of straight lines or other things. Thanks in advance!

Source: Problem-11 Tristan Needham Visual Complex Analysis page-46

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think it represents a circle. The line joining $a,b$ can be treated as a chord of this circle. This equation necessarily means that you have to find a locus of points which subtend a constant angle on a line segment. Such a curve is circle. You have to verify whether its just an arc or a complete circle.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441754/108128

Answer (score 3):

**What is $\boldsymbol{\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)}$?**

$$
\begin{align}
\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)
&=\arg\left(\frac{a-z}{b-z}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\arg(a-z)-\arg(b-z)
\end{align}
$$
[image]

That is, $\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)$ is the counterclockwise angle from $b$ to $a$ as viewed from $z$.

---

**For a given $\boldsymbol{\theta}$, what is the locus of $\boldsymbol{\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=\theta}$ ?**

The [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) says that the locus of points at which the angle from $b$ to $a$ is $\theta$ is an arc of a circle containing $a$ and $b$ so that the angle from $b$ to $a$ at the center of the circle is $2\theta$:

[image]

Comment: Where did you find $$\begin{align}
\arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)
&=\arg\left(\frac{a-z}{b-z}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\arg(a-z)-\arg(b-z)
\end{align}$$? It seems to be inconsistent with traditional identities for $\tan^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}y$. Just asking.

Comment: @CyeWaldman: $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)\pmod{2\pi}$

Comment: Thanks. I see now how to derive that from $$\theta=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{z}{z^*}\right)$$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\arg\frac{z-a}{z-b}=\theta$$
Recall that $\arg w=\arctan\frac{\Im w}{\Re w}$

If $a=p+qi;\;b=r+si$ then

$$\arg\frac{z-a}{z-b}=\arctan\frac{-p s+p y+q r-q x-r y+s x}{p r-p x+q s-q y-r x-s y+x^2+y^2}$$

Apply $\tan$ to both sides and get

$$\frac{-p s+p y+q r-q x-r y+s x}{p r-p x+q s-q y-r x-s y+x^2+y^2}=\tan\theta$$

Which can be rearranged and give the equation of a circle

$$x^2+y^2+hx+ky+j=0$$
where, called $\tan\theta=t$

$h= \left(-p+\frac{q}{t}-r-\frac{s}{t}\right)$

$k= \left(-\frac{p}{t}-q+\frac{r}{t}-s\right)$

$j=p r+\frac{p s}{t}-\frac{q r}{t}+q s$